# webpack JQuery Duplicate Identifier 'export'

Tags: jquery, angular, webpack, typescript-typings

I'm using angular2 and webpack, not sure what happened, I did NPM install to get html2canvas and it's typings and start getting this error.  I tried removing html2canvas and still the same thing.  Can some help help?

```
ERROR in C:\Users\xxxx\Desktop\project\d3\node_modules\@types\jquery\index.d.t
s
(3779,5): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'export='.

ERROR in C:\Users\xxxx\Desktop\project\d3\typings\globals\jquery\index.d.ts
(3217,5): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'export='.
```

tsconfig.js

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": false,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
    "noImplicitUseStrict":false
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "**/*.spec.ts"
  ],
  "awesomeTypescriptLoaderOptions": {
    "useWebpackText": true
  },
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "buildOnSave": false,
  "atom": { "rewriteTsconfig": false }
}
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "starter-project",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "scripts": {
    "tsc": "tsc --rootDir src --outDir dist",
    "postinstall": "typings --proxy \"http://www-proxy.web.boeing.com:31060\" install",
    "build": "webpack --progress",
    "build:prod": "webpack -p --progress",
    "serve": "webpack-dev-server --inline --progress --port 4000 --content-base src",
    "start": "npm run serve"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-server": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "3.0.0",
    "@angular/upgrade": "2.0.0",

    "angular2-highcharts": "^0.5.5",
    "angular2-in-memory-web-api": "0.0.20",
    "core-js": "2.4.1",
    "d3": "^4.4.0",

    "ie-shim": "0.1.0",
    "jquery": "3.1.1",
    "moment": "^2.17.0",
    "mydatepicker": "^1.1.15",
    "ng2-vis": "0.0.5",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.3",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.12",
    "zone.js": "~0.6.23"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "css-loader": "0.25.0",
    "expose-loader": "^0.7.1",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "2.22.0",
    "raw-loader": "0.5.1",
    "to-string-loader": "^1.1.5",
    "ts-loader": "0.8.2",
    "typescript": "^2.0.3",
    "typings": "1.4.0",
    "webpack": "1.13.2",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.16.1"
  }
}
```

typings.json

```
{
  "globalDependencies": {
    "core-js": "registry:dt/core-js#0.0.0+20160914114559",
    "jquery": "registry:dt/jquery#1.10.0+20160908203239",
    "node": "registry:dt/node#6.0.0+20160925070332"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "d3": "registry:npm/d3#3.0.0+20160723033700"
  }

}
```

Comment: You know you can copy and paste the text from the console window, right? Then other people would be able to find this question easier if they have the same issue.

Comment: thanks for the tip, fixed.